# OpenLDAP: Is is possible to create an LDAP DB with empty suffx?

Tags: openldap

Is it possible to create an OpenLDAP database with empty suffix? If yes, how?

I was able to create the `olcDatabaseConfig` below `cn=config`, but when I try to add my first entry to the DB I get the error "no write access to parent".

My LDAP config looks like this

```
root@h12345678:~ # ldapsearch -H ldapi:// -Q -Y EXTERNAL -LLL -b "cn=config" "(objectClass=olcDatabaseConfig)"

dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcFrontendConfig
olcDatabase: {-1}frontend
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to dn.exact="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
olcSizeLimit: 500
olcPasswordHash: {ARGON2}

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth manage by * break
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix:
olcAccess: {0}to * by * write
```

My test LDIF is

```
root@h12345678:~ # cat ./test.ldif
dn: dc=net
objectClass: domain
dc: net
```

`ldapadd` yields

```
root@h2917298:~ # ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./test.ldif 
adding new entry "dc=net"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
        additional info: no write access to parent
```

*Question:* What am I doing wrong? Or is this simply not supported?

#### Background (In case you wonder, why I want this)

I need to manage three DIT which already differ on the top-most RDN, basically something like

- dc=first-domain,dc=net
- dc=second-domain,dc=com
- dc=third-domain,dc=de

Previously, these DIT were stored in three different databases, each database had one of the DNs as its database suffix. But this approach required that I also always had to specify one of these suffixes as the search base for `ldapsearch`. It was not possible to run a single search across all three DIT at once. I have only recently learned that even though the search base must not be null, an empty search base `''` is valid, i.e. `ldapsearch -b '' '(uid=foo)'` is a valid LDAP search. But this only seems to work, if there is also a database which serves the "empty" base.

In essence, I want all three DIT in a single database and be able to run a single search, e.g. for a UID, on all three DITs at once.